# Integrate $t^2y'=-5ty$

Tags: integration

I'm reading the notes and it says:

$t^2y'=-5ty$ where $y=y(t)$

Using direct integration we can conclude that $y=kt^{-5}$

I don't understand how this can be integrated directly. I can see that the solution is correct, but how did they achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a separable differential equation.

To understand why, write $y'=\frac{dy}{dt}$

$$t^2y'=-5ty$$

$$t^2\frac{dy}{dt}=-5ty$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int\frac{-5dt}{t}$$

$$\ln|y|=\ln|t^{-5}|+C$$

$$y=Ct^{-5}$$

Comment: Thanks :) All solutions were nice, but I particularly liked this one

Comment: No problem! you may want to read up on separable differential equations. They're a great introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Write the ODE in this form

$$y'=-\frac5ty$$
hence we get
$$y(t)=c\exp\left(-5\int \frac{dt}{t}\right)=ct^{-5},\; c\in\Bbb R$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
t^2y'=-5ty\Longrightarrow t^5y'+5t^4y=0 \Longrightarrow (t^5 y)'=0
\Longrightarrow t^5y=k \Longrightarrow y=kt^{-5}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Cancel $t$ at first sight. Conveniently separate the $x,y$ variables on either side of the equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{5 y }{t} $$

$$\frac{dy}{y} + \frac{5 \,dt }{t} = 0 $$

Both are logs on integration.

$$ y t ^5 = const. $$

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write $y'=\frac {dy}{dt}$: you just need to know that $\frac {y'}y=(\ln y)'$. Then

$$\frac {y'}y=-5t^{-1}$$

Integrating with respect to $dt$ (without multiplying or doing any differential-shenanigans), we get
$$
\ln y =-5\ln t+c
$$

And the result follows :-).